# JS textcontent set as only part of a string

Tags: javascript, json, populate

I'm trying to set the textcontent of an element thanks to a JSON file, but need to cut out parts of the targeted string. Does anyone know how to do that in Vanilla Javascipt ?
I'm still learning JS and haven't started Jquery yet.

The  strings in the JSON data go like this :

"image": "Fashion_Yellow_Beach.jpg". (I need textContent to be "Yellow Beach"),
another object would have "image": "Architecture_On_a_hill.jpg".  (becomes "On a hill").

Any help or even keywords that would help me find information on the web would be a relieve!

Comment: What is exactly the problem here? You can't convert `Fashion_Yellow_Beach` to `Yellow Beach`, or is there a problem with setting the `textcontent` attribute? What have you tried?

Comment: Something along the lines of `el.textContent = image.split('.')[0].split('_').slice(1).join(' ');` (keep the part before the dot, split on underscores, remove the first word, and join the rest with spaces)

Comment: @counter-integral The problem was converting  `Fashion_Yellow_Beach` to `Yellow Beach`. Thanks a lot @blex it did the trick! Do you know how .split .slice and .join are called so I can go learn more about it? If you want to set is an answer and not a comment i'll flag it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to achieve what you want.

*Click on the links above to learn more about them*, but basically:

- `str.split(separator)` will convert a String to an Array, split on a given separator
- `arr.slice(start[, end])` will extract a portion of an Array
- `arr.join(separator)` will convert an Array to a String, joining it with a separator

```js
console.log( cleanupFilename("Fashion_Yellow_Beach.jpg") );
console.log( cleanupFilename("Architecture_On_a_hill.jpg") );

function cleanupFilename(str) {
  return str            // "Fashion_Yellow_Beach.jpg"
         .split('.')[0] // "Fashion_Yellow_Beach"
         .split('_')    // ["Fashion", "Yellow", "Beach"]
         .slice(1)      // ["Yellow", "Beach"]
         .join(' ');    // "Yellow Beach"
}
```